# Roslyn - Get Syntax nodes changes from old Syntax tree

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to highlight the C# code using Roslyn, as user typing, the editor will check and highlight the corresponding text.

In Roslyn there is a way to get a new Syntax Tree from the old tree (using `SyntaxTree.WithChanges`), so I can get a new Tree as user typing. But every time the new Tree is got, I have to walk to whole tree (using `SyntaxWalker`) in order to highlight the whole code, it's very bad performance.
So is there any way I can detect the Syntax Node changes from the old tree (different with Text changes, using `SyntaxTree.GetTextChanges()`)

For example the case:

the old text : `class A {}`

the new text : `class /* A{}`

you will see the text difference is only /* , but the Syntax Node structure changes will also include the text after /* , because after /* everything is treated as comments.

How can I detect this kind of change, so that I just need to update the highlighting for specific changes

Comment: You should read the source for Roslyn's own syntax highlighting code.

Comment: I've tried to scan carefully the source of whole Roslyn project (master branch),a lot of features (code complete, highlight references...) but I could not find out the code which implements that highlight feature, one clue is the class  'AbstractDocumentDifferenceService', but no place using it, and looks like it's not exactly efficient way for that feature. (I've missed any thing ?)

Comment: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Classification/Classifier.cs,6ae19a6041cfda72 http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/Classification/ClassificationHelpers.cs,bf27e920a41cdba4

Comment: Basically, you need to collect all tokens that intersect the changed span

Comment: But what if in the case with my above example, intersecting with token maybe only token `A` but actually the remaing text '{}' also need to be highlight again, because it turns to comments? (Thanks for your infomation i will look into those classes)

Comment: No; because it's all the same comment token.

Comment: ah right !!!, you're right in that case, how about the case

before :  `class A{ class Foo }`

after: `class A { Foo }` // remove 'class'

then Token Foo from Class Declaration -> Field Declaration
(I'm aware of your idea is a good start, I wonder if in Roslyn project, those guys already handle for all cases, or I need to write by my own)
you can online test the syntax tree here: http://bdnprojects.net/CSharpSyntaxParser/